# Strange behavior with byte-addressing in Mips Assembly

Tags: assembly, mips

I have the following code, which works fine:

```
        .data
        .align 2
game:
        .space 4 * 2

        .text
        .align 2

main:
 addi   $sp, $sp, -4
 sw     $ra, 0($sp)

 la     $s0, game
 li     $t0, 1 
 li     $t1, 2
 li     $t2, 0
 li     $t3, 1
 sb     $t0, 0($s0)
 sb     $t1, 1($s0)
 sb     $t2, 2($s0)
 sb     $t3, 3($s0)
 move   $a0, $s0
 jal    print_array
 addi   $sp, $sp, 4
 lw     $ra, 0($sp)
 jr     $ra
```

when I print s0, I get the correct output:

```
 1 2 0 1
```

If I try:

```
        .data
        .align 2
game:
        .space 4 * 2

        .text
        .align 2

main:
 addi   $sp, $sp, -4
 sw     $ra, 0($sp)

 la     $s0, game
 li     $t0, 1 
 li     $t1, 2
 li     $t2, 0
 li     $t3, 1
 sb     $t0, 0($s0)
 addi   $s0, 1
 sb     $t1, 0($s0)
 addi   $s0, 1
 sb     $t2, 0($s0)
 addi   $s0, 1
 sb     $t3, 0($s0)
 move   $a0, $s0
 jal    print_array

 addi   $sp, $sp, 4
 lw     $ra, 0($sp)
 jr     $ra
```

If I now print $s0, I get:

```
 0 0 0 0
```

Can anyone help me to understand what's going on here?

I've updated to include the entire code.

Comment: What value does $s0 have before you print it in your first program and what value does it have at that point in your second program?

Comment: @Ross Ridge The first implementation,  $s0: 10000024. Second implementation, $s0: 10000026

Comment: Now compare those values to the address of `game` in both programs.

Comment: @RossRidge I'm not sure how to go about getting the address of a label in my debugger. Could I just compare $s0 before we do anything to it?

Comment: @RossRidge Using the method I described above, the address of Game in both implementations is $s0: 10000000

Comment: You're apparently not showing your entire code. Since your first program doesn't change $s0, how could have $s0 changed from 10000000 to 10000024?

Comment: @RossRidge The only thing I ommitted is the building and tearing down of the stack. $s0 gets changed to 10000024 after we put contents in it in the first implemented, in the second implementation it gets changed to 10000026.